# htaccess redirects are going to home instead of new location

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I'm getting a chain with my redirects. I'm a bit confused as to why
each page is going to the homepage before the new domain.

So in the single example I have put here, **www.myolddomain.com/2014/10/** goes to **www.myolddomain.com** then **www.mynewdomain.com**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*) /$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/.+ / [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ /$1/ [L,R=301]
</IfModule>

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.myolddomain\.com [NC]

#Redirect site
 RewriteRule ^/? https://www.mynewdomain.com? [R=301,L]

#redirects
RewriteRule ^/?2014/10/ https://www.mynewdomain.com/mypage/? [R=301,L]
```

My htaccess knowledge is limited so I'm having trouble spotting the issue. 
Any help is much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your redirect rules should be at the top before other rules that rewrite

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.myolddomain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^/? https://www.mynewdomain.com? [R=301,L]

#redirects
RewriteRule ^/?2014/10/ https://www.mynewdomain.com/mypage/? [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*) /$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/.+ / [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ /$1/ [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: I've put it in this order but it's still redirecting to home before the new domain.